# Rusting of iron is quicker in saline water than in ordinary water

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, electrolysis, corrosion, iron

I feel so because, saline water has more more electrons and because of that there will be oxidation will take place faster and hence the overall process will speed up. Is this explanation good enough or there's more to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does concentration of salt increase or decrease rate of rusting?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22043/does-concentration-of-salt-increase-or-decrease-rate-of-rusting)

Comment: @ManRow I read through it, but I still have some doubts. I can't seem to reply to the person who answered that question for some reason. Can you help me out?

Comment: You need 50 rep. to comment everywhere. BTW your explanation makes no sense :(

Comment: Leah - **HINT** In chemistry the using the right terms is vital. It isn't that "saline water has more more *electrons*" but that saline water has more more of something else...

Comment: @MaxW more of ions? Na+ and Cl- ?

Comment: Leah, yes that is it - ions, not electrons.

Comment: @MaxW Okay, but how do these ions contribute to speeding up the process of rusting?

Answer (score 0):

To quote an [educational source](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=552#:~:text=Yes%2C%20it%20accelerates%20it%20.,accelerate%20corrosion%20in%20salt%20water.):

> Water is the enabler of fast oxidation of iron so freshwater will also cause rust. However, salt water is a very good conductor (lots of dissociated ions) and so there are a number of electrolysis reactions that tremendously accelerate corrosion in salt water.

which means, in essence, that aqueous NaCl is a good electrolyte that can also promote so called galvanic corrosion reactions.